# ros melodic tf to tf2 migration

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently running ros melodic/ubuntu 18.0 and compiling this global planner code (which was written for ros indigo) gives the error message:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose(tf::Stamped<tf::Transform>&)’
       if(dynamic_costmap_->getStaticROSCostmap()->getRobotPose(robot_pose))
```

Snippet of code as follows:

```
 try
  {
    geometry_msgs::Twist prev_vel = current_plan_.velocities.at(i - 2);
    if(prev_vel.linear.x == 0 && replanning_start_vel.linear.x == 0)
    {
      ROS_DEBUG("turn in place. update pose with amcl");
      tf::Stamped<tf::Transform> robot_pose;
      if(dynamic_costmap_->getStaticROSCostmap()->getRobotPose(robot_pose))
      {
        conti_pose.pose.position.x = robot_pose.getOrigin().getX();
        conti_pose.pose.position.y = robot_pose.getOrigin().getY();
      }
   }
  }
```

i'm suspecting this is because of the migration from tf to tf2. However i am really new to ROS and coding in general. I have tried reading the tf ros wiki, but it's really complicated and seems like i have to get a full understanding behind the workings of tf.

So i was wondering if there is any quick fix or how can i rewrite this  particular part of the code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337321/ros-melodic-tf-to-tf2-migration/) by [marcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/49229/marcs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn: ah yes this seemed to do the trick, along with the tweaking of other lines in the code
Found out a method which was to compare 2 same codes from diff versions side by side (i compared goal_functions.cpp from Indigo and Melodic era) and simply played spot the difference

this is the edited code which compiled:

```
 geometry_msgs::PoseStamped robot_pose;
      if(dynamic_costmap_->getStaticROSCostmap()->getRobotPose(robot_pose))
      {
        conti_pose.pose.position.x = robot_pose.pose.position.x;
        conti_pose.pose.position.y = robot_pose.pose.position.y;
```

also i added a few header files

```
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h>
#include <tf2/utils.h>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
```

thanks for your help, it was greatly appreciated :)

---

Originally posted by [marcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/49229/marcs/) with karma: 18 on 2019-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-12**:\

> So i was wondering if there is any quick fix or how can i rewrite this particular part of the code?

So in the end I would say: no, there is no "quick fix".

If trying to get code from 5 years ago to compile against current versions of ROS packages, there is a very good chance you'll have to port the code and accommodate for chances that the new version(s) of your dependencies have gone through.

This is not unique to ROS packages of course but something that applies to all software.